# How to hide or show div on click in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have four HTML `div` I want to show and hide them on click how to do this

```
            <div id="targetid" class="image_one"><img src="image/imageone.png"/></div>
            <div id ="targetidone "class="image_two"><img src="image/imagetwo.png"/></div>
            <div id="targetidtwo" class="image_one_one"><img src="image/pagetwo_graph_two_11.png"/></div>
            <div id ="targetidfour"class="image_two_two"><img src="image/pagetwo_graph_two_22.png"/></div>
```

below are those two `div` on which after click the above image should hide and show

```
          <div class="option_image"><img src="image/option_1.png"/></div>

          <div class="option_image_one"><img src="image/option_1.png"/></div>
```

Comment: @UmerHayat  i think so if you know other please tell

Comment: If you had searched google, you could have found about 1 mil. examples on how to do this. I will vote this question down.

Comment: @Rob Guess what the first search result is when googling 'html show hide div'...

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu Let me quess.....this post? :-)

Comment: @Rob Yup. It's a bit disconcerting to hit the first result and reach a post with -4 votes. I understand the original downvoting on the sloppy writing and laziness of the OP, but maybe you could reconsider. The post is in fairly good shape now, and together with the answers it provides real value.

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu no problem, i removed my downvote!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("buttonid").click(function () {
$("divid").toggle();
});
```

Buttonid - Id of the button which you will click
divid - Id of the div which you need to show/hide

note:include jquery script

Comment: i did not understand can you describe a little bit as my code shown

Comment: To use an ID in a jQuery selector it needs to be prefixed with a hash: `$("#buttonid")` etc

Comment: I've edited the answer with a link, but here it is again: [jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery)

Comment: @steve: prefix is not necessary in all cases.

Comment: @JacksonJ: Add id tag to your image divs, call a common js function say "togglediv", make it simple by passing the div id which should be shown/hidden as a parameter to the "togglediv" function,
Now append the parameter in the code as $(@param).toggle();

Comment: @Thiliban correct, however omitting the hash would mean selecting based on a tag name and not an ID

Answer (score 4):

If you don't use any 3rd party javascript (eg: jQuery), then use it:

```
document.getElementById('target-id').style.display = 'none'; // hide it
document.getElementById('target-id').style.display = 'block'; // show it (for block element, eg: div)
document.getElementById('target-id').style.display = 'inline'; // show it (for inline element, eg: span)
```

Example (1):

```
<div id="target-id">hello workd</div> <!-- attribute: id -->
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('target-id').style.display = 'none'; return false;">hide it</a> 
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('target-id').style.display = 'block'; return false;">show it</a>
```

Example (2):

```
<div id="targetid" class="image_one" onclick="document.getElementById('targetid').style.display = 'none';"><img src="image/imageone.png"/></div> <!-- adding onclick to hide this element when you click it -->

<div class="option_image" onclick="document.getElementById('targetid').style.display = 'block';"><img src="image/option_1.png"/></div> <!-- adding onclick to show element #targetid when you click this -->
```

Comment: i want that when page load firt two dic should be visible and when i click on button second div should open i have added your code but not working

Comment: Just adding my code above will not make it works.

You need to add id="something" in your target elements (the elements to show/hide). And make sure that it is unique (no other elements have the same id).

After that, put the onclick="..." in your trigger elements (the elements that when clicking on it, will show/hide the target elements).

And it will be easier when you use 3rd party library, eg jQuery.

Comment: See example (2). I've added some onclick from your code. You can extend it for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As muhhamad alvin has posted, you may want to reverse the way things are displayed. So, tweaking his solution gave me this result:

How it functions?

-Click on Question to show an Answer, click on Answer to hide the Answer (Question is always displayed). So, just replace the Question and Answer with your own divs.

```html
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('target-id').style.display = 'block'; return false;">Question</a>
<div id="target-id" style="display: none;"><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('target-id').style.display = 'none'; return false;">Answer</a> </div> <!-- attribute: id -->
```

Edit: The thing to note is that for every Question/Answer pair, you will need a different 'target-id'.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this:

$(".image_one").toggle();

the code above grab the element by name of class.
if you dont have a class there,you can get by id just like this:

$("#image_one").toggle();

hope this useful

Comment: Author asked to hide ON CLICK, plus - it's worse version of already accepted answer posted more than 15 mins before Yours.