# Create a button that will hide other element when clicked

Tags: javascript, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript hide/show element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element)
>   [How to hide or show div on click in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222797/how-to-hide-or-show-div-on-click-in-html)

I have a [blog](http://stramaxon.blogspot.com/).
On the right sidebar, there are several gadgets, but I want to make a button that will hide a specific gadget or div element, I just need an idea, I will style the div elements and class myself.

Comment: Have you tried anything or are just asking for an answer? Or have you tried to search for an answer?

Comment: using javascript, you can document.getElementById("div-id").style.display="none" to hide.

Comment: LOL, I am sorry for this idiotic post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example http://jsfiddle.net/qRwDr/

just explain me in detail how do you want it to work, i'll help you out.

Comment: Yup ! I want that !! Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div onclick="document.getElementById('tohide').style.visibility = 'hidden';">
```

Comment: or display='none' if you want to collapse the div

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery to achieve ur requirement,

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    // perform something for eg :
    $('div').hide();
});
```

You can visit www.jquery.com for more details.

Comment: Or not. It is too simple to need jQuery if not already used elsewhere - and "live" is deprecated. It is now "on" and you forgot the quotes

Comment: PS: On static pages it is .click(...) and not .live or .on which is appropriate

Comment: Forgot quotes? Quotes for what? What he has will will work fine... Except for changing `live` to `on`. Also, that is not always right. `.click` gets translated to `.on` anyway. You need a bit more code to make `.on` to work on a dynamic page.

Comment: There were no quotes around the 'click' when I commented - and live is still deprecated

Comment: now that code works fine. you can check, as i forgot to add quotes for click.

Comment: use on or click instead of live, please

Comment: @mplungjan, please open stackoverflow website and run the below code in console 
 $('p').live('click', function(){
   $('img').hide();  
}); 
finally click on first p tag i,e. click on your question, and check whether it will or not, you can use .live instead of .on . please run the code which i posted here before commenting it as wrong.

Comment: It is not wrong in principle. It will still work. Just never use deprecated calls, especially not as answers to inexperienced javascripters. Or do you not know what [deprecated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation) means? _As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()._ And in my opinion it is clearer to use [.click(...)](http://api.jquery.com/click/) in this particular case

Comment: Yeah if u knew this much info why did u asked for idea? I gave only idea mate, here u ll get an idea to solve ur problem not the solution. Yeah I do agree ur point but I just said you can use some kinda code as I posted above.

Comment: $('p').on('click', function() {
  $('img').hide();
});

i agree your point mate :)